# HazelCast configuration generates a lot members

Tags: hazelcast

I'm trying to add hazelcast to my project. the configuration below generates a lot of members.
What I need is only tow.

**Configuration**

```
    <hz:hazelcast id="instance">
    <hz:config>
        <hz:group name="mass-storage-${env}" password="tomcat-${env}"></hz:group>
        <hz:properties>
            <hz:property name="hazelcast.merge.first.run.delay.seconds">5</hz:property>
            <hz:property name="hazelcast.merge.next.run.delay.seconds">5</hz:property>
        </hz:properties>
        <hz:network port="${hazelcast.config-cluster.discovery-port}" port-auto-increment="false">
            <hz:join>
                <hz:multicast enabled="false"/>
                <hz:tcp-ip>
                    <hz:member>${hazelcast.config-cluster.address-1}</hz:member>
                    <hz:member>${hazelcast.config-cluster.address-2}</hz:member>
                </hz:tcp-ip>
            </hz:join>
        </hz:network>
        <hz:map name="driveAccessTokensCache">
            <hz:near-cache time-to-live-seconds="${drive.access.token.ttl.seconds}" max-idle-seconds="10" eviction-policy="LRU" invalidate-on-change="true" max-size="5000"/>
    </hz:map>
        <hz:map name="accessTokensCache">
            <hz:near-cache time-to-live-seconds="${user.access.token.ttl.seconds}" max-idle-seconds="10" eviction-policy="LRU" invalidate-on-change="true" max-size="5000"/>
        </hz:map>
    </hz:config>
</hz:hazelcast>
```

this is what i got :

```
Members [2] {
        Member [ecarbsul1680h11]:18934 this
        Member [ecarbsul1550h11]:18934
}

03-Jun-2020 17:16:17.657 INFO [hz._hzInstance_2_dev.ServiceThread] com.hazelcast.cluster.ClusterManager.null [10.30.197.120]:5701 [dev]

Members [6] {
        Member [10.30.197.223]:18934
        Member [10.30.197.223]:5701
        Member [10.30.197.226]:18934
        Member [10.30.197.226]:5701
        Member [10.30.197.120]:5701 this
        Member [10.30.197.253]:5701
}
```

this is what i want to get :

```
  Members [2] {
            Member [ecarbsul1680h11]:18934 this
            Member [ecarbsul1550h11]:18934
    }
```

Could you please help me to know what is wrong with my configuration ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in your XML

```
<hz:hazelcast id="instance">
```

would direct Spring to create 1 @Bean of type "HazelcastInstance" with bean name "instance".

*IF* this file was used, you would see log messages mentioning the cluster name `mass-storage-${env}`.

You have a log message

```
03-Jun-2020 17:16:17.657 INFO [hz._hzInstance_2_dev.ServiceThread] com.hazelcast.cluster.ClusterManager.null [10.30.197.120]:5701 [dev]
```

that mentions a different cluster name (the default cluster name of `dev`).

So whatever is creating your Hazelcast instances isn't using this XML file, which is why it's not behaving as you had requested.

Try using `@ImportResource("classpath:hazelcast-spring.xml")` to get Spring to load the XML.

I also see mention of Tomcat. If you're using Tomcat with Hazelcast for session caching, Tomcat will create it's own Hazelcast instance unless you tell it to use an existing one. That might explain where the extra instances are coming from.

Comment: Yes ! A defaut HazelCast file was loaded
`03-Jun-2020 17:15:16.392 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] com.hazelcast.config.XmlConfigBuilder.null Could not find hazelcast.xml in classpath.
Hazelcast will use hazelcast-default.xml config file in jar.`
I fixed by adding my own hazelcast.xml file into resources folder